# How do i care for these orchids?

Tags: orchids

My father in law was an avid gardener. He passed away two weeks ago leaving behind a house and garden full of plants. We are overwhelmed as to what to do with them all.

His pride was these orchids in his kitchen.
We have been watering them occasionally for the past month but have no idea what we are doing.

We want to take them home with us but have no idea where to put them or even if they are okay. Especially the one on the right with the white (roots) sticking out.

I have googled a lot but have no idea what kind of orchid these are even.

[image: the plants]

[image: another picture]

Are these going to be okay? And how do we look after them?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You have phalaenopsis on left (shade lovers), and cattleya hybrids other 3 (sun hogs). Aerial roots are normal, but that many mean the medium is so wet that the plant is running away for air.

Comment: @YosefBaskin thank you! that gives me more to work with on google. Thanks!